# Email function list indices must be integers or slices, not function

Tags: python-3.x, list, email

```
,,, 
   def sendEmail(reciever, subject, content):
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        senderemail = 'Test3@gmail.com'
        epwd = 'Password'
        server.starttls()
        server.login(senderemail, epwd)
        email = EmailMessage()
        email['from'] = senderemail
        email['To'] = reciever
        email['Subject'] = subject
        email.set_content(content)
        server.send_message(email)
        server.close
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        wishme()
        while True:
            query = takeCommandMIC().lower()
            if 'time' in query:
                time()
            elif 'date' in query:
                date()
            elif 'email' in query:
                  email_list = {
            'John': 'test@gmail.com'
            'Alan': 'Test2@gmail.com'
            'Fraser' : 'test3@gmail.com'
        }
                try:
                    speak ('To whom should I send an Email?')
                    name = takeCommandMIC
                    reciever = email_list[name]
                    speak("What is the Subject of the Email?")
                    subject = takeCommandMIC
                    speak('What should I say?')
                    content = takeCommandMIC()
                    sendEmail(reciever, subject, content)
                    speak("Email has been sent")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    speak("Unable to send the Email")
            elif 'offline' in query:
                quit()
,,,
```

Hi everyone,

above is my code and I am struggling to understand what is causing my issue. when I run the code it comes up saying 'list indices must be integers or slices, not function' I am trying to have the assistant respond to where it can choose the recipient based on the name spoken.

```
Trace:


PS C:\Users\rober> & C:/Users/rober/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/rober/Documents/Python/JARVIS.py
  File "c:\Users\rober\Documents\Python\JARVIS.py", line 115
    'Alan': 'Test2@gmail.com'
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS C:\Users\rober>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - your code is not runnable at the moment. Also, what is the stack trace of the issue?

Comment: Hi Sophros, I have updated with MRE

Comment: What about a stack trace?

Comment: Sorry missed that, how do I print the stack trace ive never had to do that before

Comment: You do not _print_ stack trace. Please refer to [this article](https://www.scalyr.com/blog/python-stack-trace-understanding-using-debug/#:~:text=What%20Is%20a%20Python%20Stack,traceback%2C%20backtrace%2C%20or%20traceback.&text=In%20other%20words%2C%20a%20stack,function%20that%20raised%20an%20exception.)

Comment: The trace is now above

Comment: Thanks for the link, explained it well!

Answer (score 1):

That's easy. You can't lookup a name in a list of dictionaries. Try:

```
email_list = {
   'John': 'test@gmail.com'
   'Alan' : 'Test2@gmail.com'
   'Fraser' : 'test3@gmail.com'
}
```

There's no visible reason why you store each receiver as its own dictionary in a list.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and the : makes it expect an expression and asks for them to be separated with semicolons